# Binding 40 Sockets to 40 different IP addresses

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming, udp

I am writing on UDP server/client application.

I want my single server to handle 40 clients at a time. For this, I want to create 40 dedicated threads, each dedicated for one single client. Since there are 40 threads one for each client, I want to create 40 dedicated sockets as well.

But the problem that:

I don't know what will be the 40 IP addresses to which I shall bind() my sockets. (since as far as I now, I have to bind() to my Server\s IP address.)  Normally I bind() to `"INADDR_ANY"` when there is only single socket.

But what should be the IP addresses at which I should bind() each of my 40 sockets?
Please help me. Any comment/ help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need 40 sockets (socket addresses) or 40 IP addresses? Will your host have so many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common way to do this with UDP is:

- Server bind() to a well known port.
- Client sends the initial packet to that well known port
- Server receive the first packet from a client on the well known port.
- Server creates a new socket with a random port
- Server replies to the client from this new socket.
- Client receives the reply, notices it comes from another port than the well known
  server port, and uses that port as the destination for further communication.

You'll use the getpeername() call to learn the remote address.

Keep in mind that UDP is connection-less, you'll need some way to signal the end or time out you sockets.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` only needs the local address, not the remote address.

If you want one socket for each client, then you'll need to use different ports for each (using `bind`). That way, each client can send its traffic to a dedicated port, and you can have a thread for each socket/port.

It's probably a better idea to only have one socket (and one port) though, and have logic in your code to assign traffic to a thread based on the remote address (retrieved using `recvfrom` eg.).

Comment: If there is only a single thread and all of the 40 clients send data simultaneously on this single socket, there are chances that data of each client may get dropped. 
Due to this reason, I shifted towards creating dedicated sockets for each client.

Comment: If you really want dedicated sockets, I explained how to do that. I don't understand why you think data would get dropped if you're only using one socket though.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) really helped me :)
One thing I want to know is that what are the disadvantages if I create 40 threads/sockets instead of one listening thread. every one seems to be against this idea. Are there some solid reasons behind this? Why should one not be creating 40 dedicated threads/sockets for each client and should focus on creating one socket? :(

Comment: various reasons, but most importantly : it just doesn't scale very well (what if there are 400 clients, or 4000, or 40000, or ...), and is harder to configure/maintain (each client has to be configured with a different port, and each client has to be known by the server)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to [bind](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_bind.htm) a single [socket](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_socket.htm) and [accept](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_accept.htm) incoming connections. Each connection will be assigned a unique socket by accept.

As you are using UDP, I would simply use TCP as described above to let the clients know of their respective server UDP addresses.

Comment: Its the requirement of my system to create 40 sockets. Now the problem is that I don't know what IP Addresses must be bind()ed to these 40 sockets :(

Comment: @Ayesha Hassen: I augmented my answer to address UDP.

Answer (score 1):

Create a single listening socket in a dedicated listening thread.

When it receives a new packet, use the packet's remote addr/port, or put a unique clientID in the packet payload, to uniquely identify the client.

Create a new thread for that client if one does not already exist, pass the packet to that thread for further processing, and go back to listening.

If a given client thread does not receive any packets for awhile, it can terminate itself.